# How to solve the error-Error loading file "Excel2007": Could not open Excel2007 for reading! while reading excel file using PHPExcelFile?

Tags: php, excel

> myfile.xlsx is the name of file to be opened.I have used PHPExcel
>   library(a very common library) but i could not not find the code to
>   read the excel file and display it into sentence or in browser.Plz
>   help .

```
try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify('myfile.xlsx');
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileType);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileType, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
    $array_data = array();
    foreach ($rowIterator as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
        $array_data[$rowIndex] = array('A' => '', 'B' => '', 'C' => '', 'D' => '', 'E' => '', 'F' => '', 'G' => '');

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if ('A' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('B' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('C' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('D' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('E' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('F' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if ('G' == $cell->getColumn()) {
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Make sure that the file is in the current working directory, or specify the filepath to the file correctly. Make sure that your application has privilege to actually read the file

Comment: it is in the current file directory

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to open a file called `Excel2007` (the value of `$inputFileType`) when your file is called `myfile.xlsx`

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('myfile.xlsx');
```